# CSS Table responsive - stacking a column under another column

Tags: css, responsive-design, html-table, responsive

I'm creating a table, and was wondering how to move a column below another column when minimizing the browser.

I'd like to accomplish something like this:

```
Title1 | Title2
Info1  | Info2
-------|--------
       | Title3
       | Info3
```

The original state:

```
Title1 | Title2 | Title3
Info1  | Info2  | Info3
-------|--------|------


<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Title1
      </th>
      <th>
        Title2
      </th>
      <th>
        Title3
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Info1
      </td>
      <td>
        Info2
      </td>
      <td>
        Info3
      </td>
    </tr>    
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This would also need to be for email templates, so would need help in regards to allowing the styling to work across browsers/email providers/devices

Comment: I wouldn't use a table for this instead look into css grids they are pretty well supported and very flexible. Check out this [tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

Comment: @DavidVillarreal hi, i forgot to mention (which I just edited), I need it working in email, I don't think css grid is supported amongst a lot of browsers yet

Comment: oh then ya a table would be a better choice for emails but wouldn't know how to do. There is, however, a great tool to preview your html/css in emails check out [mailchimp](https://mailchimp.com/).